# How to fix E5000: No bank links are configured for merchant [merchant_id]?

Tags: php, api, payment-gateway

I have had implemented the Commweb payment integration 3-Party with PHP on my site where users can pay with credit cards using master card payment gateway. From last couple of days I am receiving errors from my users that the transactions are failing. I just checked it today and I found that its throwing an error which I wasnt able to find in the implementation docs. The error message returned is:

**E5000: No bank links are configured for merchant [merchant_id]**

Anyone has idea on how to fix this issue? Please help...

URL for ref:

**.../commweb/commweb_postreturn.php?Title=PHP+VPC+3-Party&button=Make+a+Credit+Card+Deposit&vpc_Amount=4300&vpc_BatchNo=0&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_Locale=en&vpc_MerchTxnRef=TESTERAC-454545&vpc_Merchant=TESTTERM01&vpc_Message=E5000%3A+No+bank+links+are+configured+for+merchant+%5BTESTER123%5D.&vpc_OrderInfo=CommWeb+Gateway+Payment&vpc_SecureHash=B38E67D6311C43D4AF0118270DEEB20E&vpc_TransactionNo=0&vpc_TxnResponseCode=7&vpc_Version=1**

- I have changed few parameters in the URL text which could expose my account details.

Comment: This sounds like a case for their support

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact error but I am using ANZ eGate. Give the bank technical support team a call and find out why... in my case it's account closing due to a long period of inactivity!